# Looping through columns of Pandas to subtract values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to subtract the mean value of a column instead of manually selecting each column one by one

I read on another question that one can iterate over columns in pandas by using:

```
for column in df:
    print(df[column])
```

Which I have tried and this works, it prints out the columns. I have been manually calculating the mean of columns

```
average_curtain_price = df["Curtain price"].mean()

new_average = df["Curtain price"] - average_curtain_price 

print(new_average.mean())
```

The new average is returned as a negligible number so I know this code works, but when I try to use it in the iterative loop:

```
for column in df:
    column = column - df[column].mean()
```

Returns the error,

> File "", line 2, in 
>       column = column - df[column].mean()
>
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'

I am unsure why this is happening. Does the loop somehow convert some of the columns to strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems need select Series by `df[column]`:

```
for column in df:
    out = df[column] - df[column].mean()
```

If need working with first 5 columns use indexing:

```
print (df.columns[:5])

for column in df.columns[:5]:
    out = df[column] - df[column].mean()
```

If need subtract all values by means:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
})

df = df - df.mean()
print (df)
     B    C         D
0 -0.5  1.5 -1.833333
1  0.5  2.5  0.166667
2 -0.5  3.5  2.166667
3  0.5 -1.5  4.166667
4  0.5 -3.5 -1.833333
5 -0.5 -2.5 -2.833333
```

Comment: thank you very much!! I think this works. I failed to remember that of all my columns, the last one is a list of names, and hence I am unable to perform a calculation on this column. Do you know if there is a method similar to for i in range(...): whereby it can iterate and stop at a specified column number?

Comment: @Louise - Main question is need iterate? But `for column in df` is same like `for column in df.columns`, so if need iterate first 5 columns use indexing like `for column in df.columns[:5]`